# How do I list my currently open open files in Xcode?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

**VS Code** has a nice feature which shows your working files on the upper left corner. **Visual Studio** doesn't have it, but there's a plugin that makes it possible in **Visual Studio** too, which can be found [on the marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Ant-f.WorkingFilesList).

Is there anything like this in **Xcode** or for **Xcode**? How do switch on that view/panel/dialog in **Xcode**, or how do I install a plugin that will do it?

This is very handy when you have a very large solution open, with some 100 projects and have 10 files open in the editor and each of them belong to a different project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Xcode doesn't have plugins (anymore). They don't have a feature exactly like the one in VSCode, but you can have the left panel show some recently opened files with the clock icon on the bottom of the navigator panel (see photo).

[image: clock icon]

Also, if you are willing to lose a couple of first-party features, you can do some hacking around to do your swift development in VSCode: https://nshipster.com/vscode/